# favicon working in all browsers except Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, browser, favicon

I am generating the favicon programatically from ASP.NET using C# which works fine in all browsers except for Chrome.

I'm passing the page to the method SetFavIcon and setting it using HtmlLink class which is forms part of the System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace. This is how I'm doing it;

```
public static void SetFavIcon(Page p)
    {
        HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
        link.Attributes.Add("type", "image/'x-icon");
        link.Attributes.Add("rel", "shortcut icon");
        link.Attributes.Add("href", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + "/_graphics/_icons/favicon.ico");
        p.Header.Controls.Add(link);
    }
```

I've tried several options such as changing the type, adding a query string after favicon.ico but can't figure out why it is only happening in Chrome (works fine in Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, and Microsoft Edge).

I'm testing on the latest version of Google Chrome - Version 49.0.2623.112 m

Answer (score 0):

Check the whole `<head>` section of your page and look for non-header markups (`div`, `p`, etc.). For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My page</title>
    <div>This div has nothing to do here!!</div>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Unlike Firefox or IE, when Chrome encounters a non-header markup in the header, it considers it to be over and supposes this is the beginning of the body. And because the `link` markup is not body-related, Chrome simply ignores all links that appear after the faulty non-header markup. So in the example above, the `title` works (it is before the `div`) but not the `link`.

Comment: <Meta>, <Title>, <Link>, and <Script> tags are the only markups I have in the header. I'm 100% sure all non-header markups are not present in the header.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help. I have diagnosed this several times as the cause of the "favicon works everywhere but in Chrome" issue. Hopefully that will help future readers !